# xdk webview alert android theme

Tags: android, themes, alert, intel-xdk

Using Xdk to build android app. And when i debug the app, an apk is sent to my device, and the theme looks modern, the alert dialog (js) that pops has a holo style...

But when i use the build, somehow that build theme version is very ugly, maybe android 1.6 ? Why is that happening? can that be changed? i dont have access to the manifest directly, although i can append things to the manifest, but adding to elements of type application will give a build error ( because of duplicate)...

Answer (score 0):

After days of try and error, i finnaly managed to be able to alter the final theme of the build version.

For that, i hacked a plugin.xml i had on the project directory and under platform=android i added this:

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml"  parent="/manifest">

         <application android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
         <activity android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" 
         android:name="xdk.intel.cordova.template.lite.MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application >
     </config-file>
```

Comment: That's what you have to do. :( We're working on some updates to make the default build themes and the theme in App Preview consistent. What would be even better, is a way to allow you to specify the theme, during the build (that's not so easily done for App Preview).